# Run a Selenium script on a remote machine

Tags: firefox, remote-desktop, xorg, headless, selenium

I have a small Selenium script written in Python, and I want it to run 24/7. I tried to run it on a remote machine without any success because I couldn't manage to run Xorg or more specifically Firefox on my remote machine. It works if I forward X to my local machine, but then it has no meaning since I need my local machine to be up and running 24/7. Is there any way to run Firefox on a remote machine without any display? I don't need to see anything. I just want my Selenium script to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can use Firefox in headless mode by passing `--headless` argument while webdriver creating:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

args = Options()
args.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=args)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Once again I understand how important it is to read documentation carefully.